# Products not displaying in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

Pulling my hair out here trying to troubleshoot the reason why some new products aren't displaying on the frontend. I've checked the usual stock, weight, visibility, etc and have reindexed and recached plenty of times.

Can anyone think of anything else that could be causing this?

(Also, these products are counted in the result counts for searches, but not actually shown)

Update: products can be accessed directly via their URL/ID, but they aren't showing up in the categories/search results.

Comment: Are all the products not showing up?

Comment: Only new products aren't showing up, the old products do

Comment: Do you have a multi store setup?

Comment: No, just the one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A command I hadn't tried before fixed this:

```
bin/magento indexer:reset
```

In the past, I'd only used "reindex", but a reset was necessary in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Is your product set to "enabled" and is the visibility set to "Catalog, Search"?
Stock availability should also be set to "In stock".

Once you have confirmed that, if you are using any associated products, make sure at least one of them has stock.

From my experience once you have met the above conditions and reindexed/cache, your products should appear. If not it might be a conflict with one of your extensions or code.

It's strange that they are included in the result count in a search without being shown...

Comment: Yeah, I've checked all of this. Strange, right?